# IntelliJ Process finished with exit code 0 when spring-boot run

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have a problem when starting spring-boot appication from IntelliJ-Idea. I don't have this problem when running application through terminal.

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)

2015-09-24 12:22:44.274  WARN 22380 --- [           main] n.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration   : Cache 'publicationsCount' is set to eternal but also has TTI/TTL set.  To avoid this warning, clean up the config removing conflicting values of eternal, TTI and TTL. Effective configuration for Cache 'publicationsCount' will be eternal='true', timeToIdleSeconds='0', timeToLiveSeconds='0'.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think this warn is not causing it. What may be the reason?

Comment: Exit code 0 means, the application was ended without errors. So what is the problem?

Comment: But it shouldn't close. Spring-boot should wait running, waiting for requests.

Comment: Only if you have included a web server in the application, which you didn't specify. So if you want more help, you should post the relevant configuration.

Comment: A silly cause can be a wrong class in the `SpringApplication.run()`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Deleting *provided* scope of *spring-boot-starter-tomcat* dependency helps me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, I deleted my gradle equivalent: 
`providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'`

Comment: This worked. But can you please tell me why this worked. Is it because 'provided' means that it only is available during compilation?.

Answer (score 38):

I create a simple project from https://start.spring.io/ (sprint initializr) and added a simple controller to run the application.

```
@RestController
public class testController {

    @GetMapping(value="/")
    //@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello World!!";
    }
}
```

but it wasn't getting started because my pom wasn't having

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding this my application started...

```
2019-11-05 14:33:32.302  INFO 39079 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@dd20ebc, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@57b1ec84, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2c2a7d53, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@b9b97ad, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@29f3185c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4ffa7041, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@2c2a903f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@6c70b7c3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@48d44b46, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5cbe95b1, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@11ad095c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@16a09809, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1de85972, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4a122e68, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5d37aa0f]
2019-11-05 14:33:32.392  INFO 39079 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-05 14:33:32.398  INFO 39079 --- [           main] eModelDeploymentServiceParentApplication : Started ServiceModelDeploymentServiceParentApplication in 5.727 seconds (JVM running for 6.778)
```

Here are my pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note: You may be not needing all the dependencies above.

Comment: Adding spring-boot-starter-web dependency solved my issue

Comment: for `intellij`, after add dependency, click right side `Maven` menu > `Reload`

Answer (score 25):

Adding spring boot starter web solved my problem

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you create a project `gradle` template from https://start.spring.io/ (sprint initializr), you need to add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` dependecy in you build.gradle file.

```
// you need to add this dependency to run spring boot correctly
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

Comment: . Why this is not done with Spring Initializr is beyond me. I replaced: `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'` with `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'` 

Answer (score 6):

Add the below dependencies in pom.xml :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This worked for me, using Kotling Spring Boot 

Answer (score 3):

Using the below dependencies in pom.xml, as well as loading maven changes (ctrl+shift+o) solved my problem.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In my case, I had misakenly added `spring-web` instead of `spring-boot-starter-web`

Comment: also check intellij File > Project Structure > Module, Source Folder is set

Answer (score 1):

in my case i started intelliJ as

> adminstrator

, then it works
make sure you have tomcat dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I forgot to add the Spring Web MVC Dependency

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is a slight difference between:

- Just click Run in the most visible bottom inside IntelliJ and...
- Look for the default controller inside src/main/java/com.exampler.yourapplication, right click and press Run there.

The second option just run the project properly.

Comment: Thank you, second solution didn't worked for me. But at least it shows diferent error...

Answer (score 0):

If below property was added to the allication.properties file, need to remove this.
This property is used to remove the web container.

`spring.main.web-application-type=none`

In my case I forgot to remove this and once it's removed the issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to remove several dependencies first. Then I run `maven clean`. After that my code just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me removing the check-mark from - use settings from .mvn/maven.config and changing the Maven path to take from Bundled Maven worked. These settings are in build tools Maven settings.