# Springboot Application exits immediately

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I run my `spring boot` application , it exits immediately (with `exit code 0`) with this:

```
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2018-11-27 14:08:31.219  INFO 94920 --- [  restartedMain] c.springbootsecurity.jwt.JwtApplication  : Starting JwtApplication on 1000810002637M.local with PID 94920 (/Users/723305/Documents/spring/springbootSecure/target/classes started by 723305 in /Users/723305/Documents/spring/springbootSecure)
2018-11-27 14:08:31.222  INFO 94920 --- [  restartedMain] c.springbootsecurity.jwt.JwtApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-27 14:08:31.252  INFO 94920 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2018-11-27 14:08:31.722  INFO 94920 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-11-27 14:08:31.743  INFO 94920 --- [  restartedMain] c.springbootsecurity.jwt.JwtApplication  : Started JwtApplication in 0.752 seconds (JVM running for 1.294)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springbootSecurity</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>jwt</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>        
</project>
```

Comment: Please add more detail. You've just post a lot of code and your `pom`, we don't know the situation and what you've tried yet

Comment: So , I created an app using spring initialiser and tried to run it , it displays the above message . Most of the posts on google suggests to remove <scope>provider</scope> for dependency tomcat , but I don't have it

Comment: You don't show your main(), or any of your own beans?  Is there any code of yours in there?

Comment: @moilejter no , I just created the application using springinitializer and it doesn't even run . I only have the main class.                                                            `
@SpringBootApplication
public class JwtApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(JwtApplication.class, args);
    }
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758996/intellij-process-finished-with-exit-code-0-when-spring-boot-run . I think this will help u.

Comment: nope, I don't have tomcat dependency .

Answer (score 19):

Because of you spring boot in pom.xml you did not declare as starter web project it will
shut down immediately, it is an expected behavior, now to run as web container you need to add below code in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have spring-boot-started-web dependency, but it is still exit.

Comment: I had this problem also, and I had the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.  But I inadvertently excluded the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency that web normally brings in, and forgot to add a suitable replacement.  My solution was to add `spring-boot-starter-jetty`.

Answer (score 9):

I've just have the problem with IntelliJ (even with the `spring-boot-starter-web`) and solve it by editing the launcher and check `Include dependencies with "Provided" scope` option.

The web app was working fine from the command line.

Comment: you should add  `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
`

Comment: As I wrote: "event with the spring-boot-starter-web" ;-)

Comment: I had the same problem in intellij, but instead fixed it by right clicking the project -> maven -> reload project after switching the dependencies as described

Comment: Above worked. I had to reimport the project (right click on project root folder -> Maven -> Reimport). It seems to be an issue with IntelliJ possibly detecting early on as standalone desktop project and later properly recognises as web project and initialises Tomcat (binds to the port and waits for connections).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues with this.

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

This says process ended happily.

Given your application is not having `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency then it won't be starting any server and not waiting for any request.

It is very much similar to a main method which does not have anything to execute or finishes as soon as main code completes.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>.  even this doesn't work

Comment: ok do you still get the same logs ? Any logs like "tomcat started on port 8080" not coming ?

Comment: Very strange. Seems like web dependency is not added to your classpath. Can you just reimport all dependency of your module and restart the application.

Comment: Executing maven clean install will reimport all dependency

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. None of the dependencies like `spring-boot-starter-web` or removing dependency `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` didn't work. I was using IntelliJ Idea IDE community version. I think it is something to do with the IntelliJ Idea Community Version, as they mention that spring is not supported in the community version, only in the ultimate (commercial) version, at least for mac.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac

The reason of my thinking because I switched to visual studio code, installed the necessary plugins for spring boot and it worked out of the box, with my existing `pom.xml` file.

My current dependencies are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

May be worth to mention that also works without the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency.

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web` is needed

Answer (score 1):

I created recently a project with spring initializr, checked on the option "Spring Web" on IntelliJ and it added this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>
```

I replaced it with

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

If you're having the same issue and recently created a project on IntelliJ, you may need to replace that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run Maven Build to install all dependencies

[image: maven]

Answer (score 0):

I had created a spring-boot project using Spring Initializer with Spring 2.6.4 and Java 8 and I was facing this same issue when I tried to run the application in Intellij 2020.1 community edition.
I got the application working when I removed the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency from POM.