# Unable to serve using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

### Context

I have just started learning spring boot and bootstrapped a very very basic server. It only had following code: Here is my Java Code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Here is my Maven File: pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### PROBLEM

Project is built successfully but it stops running, instead of serving on localhost.
Code is not giving any errors. That's the main reason I am unable to debug.

#### Also:

I used `Spring Initializr` a vs code extention to bootstrap the project.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.0)

2020-12-06 16:15:14.055  INFO 75437 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 12.0.2 on mrWinsome.domain.name with PID 75437 (/Users/aman/Documents/SpringLearning/First/First/demo/target/classes started by aman in /Users/aman/Documents/SpringLearning/First/First/demo)
2020-12-06 16:15:14.058  INFO 75437 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-06 16:15:14.850  INFO 75437 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.688 seconds (JVM running for 2.253)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23.861 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-06T16:15:14+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looking at the output, it seems like you are starting the app via `mvn`. What target did you execute? After calling `mvn package`, you should find a `*.jar` file in folder `target` that you can start via `java -jar <nameOfjar>.jar`.

Comment: i simply used command: `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: Please try adding the `spring-boot-start-web` dependency to your project as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53493955/4216641)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `spring-boot-started-web` dependency. The default port is `8080`. Please see the original answer here
[Springboot Application exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492213/springboot-application-exits-immediately/53493955#53493955)

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Turing85 - What is the best practice in this case? I referenced the original answer from your comment above.

Comment: The best practice is to not answer and close the question as duplicate.